# Using l'Hopital's rule to find the limit .

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, derivatives

I need a hint to evaluate the following limit:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{\cos x}$$

Comment: Please typset your equations properly.

Comment: No need to use L'Hopital, as $cos(0) > 0$

Comment: Better than L'Hopital use sandwich theorem, start with $-1\le \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\le 1$

Comment: If I may amend what @JuliaHayward said, it's not a matter of *needing* that theorem: you *cannot* use it, since [${x^3\sin\left({1\over x^3}\right)\over\cos(x)}$ does not satisfy the first hypothesis of the theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

Comment: Squeeze theorem is  very useful. The answer is 0.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**: $\left|x^3\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right| \leq |x^3|$

Comment: maybe he's wanting a Hospital way?

Comment: L'hospital just doesn't work here because you always have to deal with a $\sin$-expression that has undefined limit. At some point you need to use this hint or something very similar. L'Hospital would not change anything. It just delays the use of the technique above.

Comment: @LeBtz I know that, my comment meant you to put up what you've wrote to me in the comments in your answer to the OP.

Comment: @ADG The original function cannot be evaluated by L'Hospital since it is not of the form $0 \over 0$. In order to used L'H you have to make it much more tedious (and I doubt whether this can succeed), while the original problem is easy to solve: clearly it is not the way we do math.

Answer (score 0):

Find the following limit:
 $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{\cos x}$$

Since $\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{\cos(x)}$ is bounded and $\lim_{x \to 0}x^3=0$:

So:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{\cos x}=0$$